# Fixed Header and Bootstrap Affix - Jump

Tags: affix

I want that the top title will be stay even when scrolling, it works, but the content will jump and seems bad.

My JS:

```
jQuery('.header').affix({
    offset: { 
    top:$('.header').offset().top 
     }
    });
```

Comment: i have the same problem and im still working on it. no idea how to fix [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779143/bootstrap-header-scroll-offset)

Answer (score 2):

add to your css:

```
.affix + .container {
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

or

```
.affix + .container {
    min-height:50px;
}
```

solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone searching for a solution I did the following

1. Added a spacer after my navbar
2. Added a rule to the css to increase the spacer when the navbar is affixed

   `<header class="navbar">...</header>
   <div class="affixSpacer"></div>`

   `.navbar.affix + .navBarAffixFixer
   {
       height:52px;/* Height of your navbar */
   }`