# Bootstrap header Scroll Offset

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, navigation

I have a logo and a header with my Navigation like this:

```
<div id="logohead">
//...
</div>   
<header id="header" class="affix navbar navbar-static" data-spy="affix" role="banner">
//...
</header><!--/#header-->
```

in my Footer i do this:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#header').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $('#logohead').height()
      }
}); 

    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#header').addClass('shrink');
    } else {
        $('#header').removeClass('shrink');
    }    
    });
});

</SCRIPT>
```

i want to resize my logotext which is in the header. the logo picture is in #logohead.
my problem is the jumping of the page in certain page sizes. if there is a special size of the browser, some pages start to jump and my script is not working. is there a fix?

EDIT:
http://jsfiddle.net/am59aakg/1/

thought i found a solution:
it makes less jumping but still not perfect.

just added

```
.affix + .container {
    padding-top:50px
}
```

but it doesn

Comment: Please provide us working fiddle

Comment: Hi, it took some time to make the fiddle. First i thought it has something to do with my sticky footer but it even makes the same thing without. http://jsfiddle.net/am59aakg/1/ resize the result window to see the effect. try to make the window smaller so you can see like half of the content or so...

Answer (score 0):

this makes it working ...more or less...:

```
.affix + div {
    margin-top:80px;
}
.affix + .page-header {
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

first try was (not working):

```
`.affix + .container {
    padding-top:50px
}`
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: sorry, i thought i found the solution but it was wrong. addes correct solution.